# Google review process for XOAuth2 protocol app

Tags: gmail, google-oauth, gmail-pop

I want to implement XOAuth2 and publish as external app.
My application support POP3 and SMTP protocol with XOAuth2.

The authentication scope need to https://mail.google.com/ because of following document.
https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol?hl=en

I implemented and submit verification from Google cloud console.
But the verify is pending because of scope.

The verification team suggest as following, I need implement following function.

```
https://mail.google.com/ scope should only be requested if your application needs to immediately and permanently delete threads and messages, bypassing Trash

Or
    
Migrate to Gmail API
```

How to pass the Google Review process?
I cannot migrate to Gmail API because SMTP/POP3 protocol is needed.

I tried to reduce the scope like https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send but it failed to connect SMTP/POP3 protocol.
So I need to use https://mail.google.com/ scope and implement "delete threads and messages bypassing trash"

Comment: Send an email back to them telling them you can't use the Gmail API and why

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo
I sent that we need to access POP3/SMTP server with XOAuth2.
The response is you need "delete threads and messages bypassing trash" to use the scope

Comment: Talk to them tell them you dont understand. They will clarify.   Tell them exactly what you are doing and what your app does.   and why you cant use the gmail api.   In the mean time i sent a message off to the team to see if we cant get some better info over to the verification team.